# how to update multi embedded documents in mongoengine

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

mongo collection as follow:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5eedb36d6cd00ed8e8748cc7"),
"user" : "5",
"search" : [
    {
        "name" : "first",
        "status" : 1
    },
    {
        "name" : "second",
        "status" : 0
    },
    {
        "name" : "third",
        "status" : 0
    }
 ] 
}
```

and models:

```
class HistoryItem(models.EmbeddedDocument):
    name = models.StringField()
    status = models.IntField()

class History(models.Document):
    user = models.StringField(unique=True)
    search = models.EmbeddedDocumentListField(HistoryItem, default=[])
```

I want to update all EmbeddedDocument's status to 1,

I try this:

```
mongo_models.History.objects(user="5", search__status=0).update(set__search__S__status=1)
```

but just update the first EmbeddedDocument which status is 0, what should I change my code to update all EmbeddedDocument. Thanks.

Comment: You tell to save just objects from user="5" and 'search__status=0 ..'

Comment: @CristiC777 tanks for your reply, I means this code just update the first EmbeddedDocuments of listfield.

Comment: I think is faster to update your Json colection first and the save it.

Comment: try : mongo_models.History.objects(user="5", search__status=0).all().update(...)

Comment: the same result, just first.. emm

Comment: strage..Debug just : test = History.objects(user="5", search__status=0).all() if return a list of 2.. or how many items you want to update ..

Comment: yes, so strange,  return a list with one element, I want to update 2 embedd-document

Comment: so that is the cause for update just one :) check configuration .. Debug..

Comment: I have find reason from  mongoengine doc, just support first match. thank you very much..

Comment: Welcome :) and have fun coding :)

Answer (score 0):

> Due to Mongo, currently the $ operator only applies to the first
> matched item in the query

from mongoengine doc.

Comment: I did not sow $ .. but S, so it's a mongo thing not django.. what is your final working code ?